# ScrollView not detect content size change

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, scrollview

I made some drawer objects and their height are changing when clicked.When first one expended i can move second drawer as well.

```
private void Frame1_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e){
   SelectedVal = ((DrawerDetailFrame)sender).SelectedValue;
   Frame2.TranslateTo(Frame2.TranslationX, SelectedVal == 275 ? Frame2.TranslationY + 200 : Frame2.TranslationY - 200, 500, Easing.SinOut);            
}
```

This is for move the second drawer amount of firsts expanded heigth.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ScrollView x:Name="skrull" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always" BackgroundColor="Red" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout Margin="22,22,18,0">
                <views:DrawerDetailFrame x:Name="Frame1" PropertyChanged="Frame1_PropertyChanged"></views:DetailFrame>
                <views:DrawerDetailFrame x:Name="Frame2"></views:DetailFrame>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="15" HasShadow="True" Padding="0,15,0,0" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="20,0,20,0">
            <BoxView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Color="White"></BoxView>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

This is page content. When both drawer frame expanded their height change not detect by scrollview. Drawers are oversize the scrollview but scrollbar not showing, not scroling.

This is Animated drawer frame code.

```
public partial class DrawerDetailFrame : ContentView {
    bool isExpanded = false;
    public DrawerDetailFrame() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height){
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

        if (isExpanded)
            Drawer1Frame.Layout(new Rectangle(Drawer1Frame.X, Drawer1Frame.Y, Drawer1Frame.Width, 275));
        else
            Drawer1Frame.Layout(new Rectangle(Drawer1Frame.X, Drawer1Frame.Y, Drawer1Frame.Width, 75));
        }

        private void Frame_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs {
            if (!isExpanded)
                AnimateIn();
            else
                AnimateOut();

             isExpanded = !isExpanded;
        }

        private void AnimateIn(){
            Drawer1Frame.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(Drawer1Frame.X, Drawer1Frame.Y, Drawer1Frame.Width, 275), 500, Easing.SinOut);
            SelectedValue = 275;
        }

        private void AnimateOut(){
            Drawer1Frame.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(Drawer1Frame.X, Drawer1Frame.Y, Drawer1Frame.Width, 75), 500, Easing.SinOut);
            SelectedValue = 75;
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedValueProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("SelectedValue", typeof(double), typeof(WalkDrawerDetailFrame), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);
        public double SelectedValue{
            get { 
                return ((double)(base.GetValue(SelectedValueProperty))); 
            }
            set { 
                SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value); 
            }
        }
}
```

Working sample.
[fullcode](https://github.com/samt1925/DrawerAnimation)

Comment: I use your code to try to reproduce your issue, but I fail, so the code above is the entire code for your sample? If not, can you provide one sample at github that can reproduce your issue? And please describe what do you want to do.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT here you go https://github.com/samt1925/DrawerAnimation

When you expand the frame drawers scroll not showing.

Comment: ,I can reproduce your issue, and I guess that scrollview don't work because of Frame in DrawerDetailFrame, so can you don't use Frame and try it again.